# Waiting for Other Processes to Complete Before Starting Main Process in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am implementing a Python application that uses multiprocessing. So, my code would look something like this,

```
# do stuff

p1 = mp.Process(target=self.__function1)

p2 = mp.Process(target=self.__function2)

p3 = mp.Process(target=self.__function3)

p4 = mp.Process(target=self.__function4)

p1.start()
p2.start()
p3.start()
p4.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
p3.join()
p4.join()

# do stuff
```

Now, I want my other processes (p1 to p4) to end before moving back to the main process. I thought this is how it worked by default. However, this is what my logs look like,

```
[2021-11-11 08:23:34,785: INFO/MainProcess] Log from MainProcess
[2021-11-11 08:23:35,178: INFO/Process-2] Log from Process-2
[2021-11-11 08:23:35,330: INFO/Process-3] Log from Process-3
[2021-11-11 08:23:35,504: INFO/Process-4] Log from Process-4
[2021-11-11 08:23:35,622: INFO/Process-5] Log from Process-5
[2021-11-11 08:25:19,344: INFO/MainProcess] Log from MainProcess
```

How can I make my main process wait for the other processes to end before starting again?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean. The `join()` calls should wait for the process to finish. Indeed, from the log output it seems it also does. What makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: you can use locks.

Comment: Because there should be some other logs that are printed from the other processes. I do not see them. The code after the `.join()` calls seem to execute before these logs appear.

Comment: How do I used locks?

Comment: What about the "Log from Process-2"? Maybe that comes from process-2?

Comment: The join will happen before _or_ after the child process finishes. That's the point of join. Realize your main process and the child processes are ran in parallel. In either case, join will wait for the child process, or return immediately if it's already finished.